# How to appear plural or singular custom taxonomy name(-s) inside woocommerce single product meta php file

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have already registered a custom taxonomy inside my theme function php file.

**Code**

```
$args = array (
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
    'labels' => array(
        'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
        'view_item' => esc_html__( 'View Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
        'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add new Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
        'new_item_name' => esc_html__( 'New Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
        'parent_item' => esc_html__( 'Parent Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Ποικιλία:', 'text-domain' ),
        'search_items' => esc_html__( 'Search Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'popular_items' => esc_html__( 'Popular Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => esc_html__( 'Separate Ποικιλίες with commas', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => esc_html__( 'Add or remove Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => esc_html__( 'Choose most used Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found' => esc_html__( 'No Ποικιλίες found', 'text-domain' ),
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Ποικιλίες', 'text-domain' ),
        'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Ποικιλία', 'text-domain' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'sort' => false,
    'rewrite_no_front' => false,
    'rewrite_hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => true,
);

register_taxonomy( 'variety-of-drink-spirits', array( 'product' ), $args );
```

Now I add on directory folder [mytheme/woocommerce/templates/singe-product/meta php] file the below code.

**Code**

```
echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'variety-of-drink-spirits', 'Ποικιλία: ', ', ', '');
```

I changed the up-stair code lines with the below.

**Code**

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'variety-of-drink-spirits', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Ποικιλία:', 'Ποικιλίες:', count( $term_ids ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ', ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

- **My question is**: How I can appearing singular or plural name of my taxonomy depend of result data.

Thank you,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution of plural and singular terms name is below.

**Code**

```
<?php $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'variety', array('fields' => 'ids') );

      echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'variety', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Ποικιλία:', 'Ποικιλίες:', count( $term_ids ), 'text-domain' ) . ' ', ', ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

In my project is working correct :)
Hope to help anyone to fix this issue !